# Do I need to commit the dist folder to git in order to be able to install the package using pip from git?

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, pip, package

I want to reuse some code for my internal team at work. My plan is to create a package and then have people install the package using `pip` straight out of our git repo. i.e. as shown here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#git

My question is, do I commit the dist folder to git? What is `pip` looking for?

Or is there a better way to share / reuse code internally for a team (across many different projects)?

I used a .gitignore file from [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) (is that github's default Python .gitignore file?) and it ignores all the dist files:

```
# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST
```

but it seems wrong to exclude these from the repo when I'm trying to install from the repo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to commit the `dist` folder.  `pip` really just needs the repository to have a `setup.py` file along with the packages and/or modules you're installing.

Comment: If that is the case, why should I create the dist folder at all? Or is that just to make the files smaller and nicely packaged for pypi? So in my case, since I am not going through pypi, I don't need to create the dist folder?

Answer (score 5):

`dist` is a default name for a directory that contains the final build result: your project ready to be *distributed*, that is, packaged into a file which `pip` or other package managers know how to install:

```
$ python setup.py sdist --help
...
  --dist-dir (-d)   directory to put the source distribution archive(s) in
                    [default: dist]
```

So it is safe to ignore the directory and all of its contents in `.gitignore`. If you do not plan to upload you project's installation files to PyPI and intend to install it via passing Git url, you don't even need the `dist` directory and can safely delete it. It will be recreated anyway once you issue any dist command (`sdist`, `bdist`, `bdist_wheel`, `bdist_rpm` etc).

Comment: So `pip` can install the package fro ma git repo *without* the dist folder created by `sdist`?

Comment: @Dan exactly, as [ldx.a.ldy.c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1375273/ldx-a-ldy-c) already pointed out in his answer: _pip really just needs the repository to have a setup.py file along with the packages and/or modules you're installing._ The only file I'm missing in his answer is the optional `setup.cfg` - if you have a non-empty one and want others to install your package with the same settings  as you have, you should push it to your repository along with the sources.

Comment: What if I will put the project in PyPI: do I still need to add it to the repository?